# Trying to Install Spotify but it says I need a non administrator account

Tags: users, spotify

When I try to install Spotify with Wine, it says I need to use a standard account. I switched my account from Administrator to standard, and restarted, but I still get the same message. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the steps [here](http://www.spotify.com/int/help/faq/wine/)?

Comment: It might be easier just to go with the native Linux client for Spotify.  While it is a touch buggy, it works 90-95% of the time.

Comment: I use the native Spotify, and have had two crashes in maybe six months. http://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/

Comment: @SirCharlo Link seems dead, what did it say?

Comment: @Aaron The other 5% of us still need to use wine, so that's not an actual solution.

Comment: @Hugo http://web.archive.org/web/20110712172206/http://www.spotify.com/int/help/faq/wine/ ;)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be occurring when Wine is configured as Windows 7. 
I ran *winecfg* and set windows version to Windows XP.

Comment: Spotify does not support windows < 7.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted in the comments, the native Spotify client is much more stable and reliable than the Wine version. If you don't require the Wine version, this is really the way to go.

> https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/